# React-Router nested routes names

Tags: react-router-v4, nested-routes, preact

I would like to implement that kind of routes in react-router v4.

```
/auth => auth home page    
/auth/login => login page    
/auth/register => register page     
/auth/forgot => lost password page      
/auth/reset => change password page
```

It doesn't work with `<Switch>` because it first match `/auth` and render the associated component. So as I click on the link to go to the `login page` for instance it renders the `Auth Component` and not the `Login Component`.

How can I implement that behavior with react-router ?
I tried nested routing but if I take the same example as before, It would renders the `Auth Component + Login Component`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the **exact** prop to your **/auth** route:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/auth' component={Auth} />
  <Route path='/auth/login' component={Login} />
  <Route path='/auth/register' component={Register} />
  <Route path='/auth/forgot' component={ForgotPassword} />
  <Route path='/auth/reset' component={ChangePassword} />
</Switch>
```

Alternatively, you could move your **/auth** route to the end of the list so other routes match first:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/auth/login' component={Login} />
  <Route path='/auth/register' component={Register} />
  <Route path='/auth/forgot' component={ForgotPassword} />
  <Route path='/auth/reset' component={ChangePassword} />
  <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
</Switch>
```

I hope this helps.